# Divisibility test algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Write a function called FooBar that takes input integer n and prints all the numbers from 1 upto n in a new line. If the number is divisible by 3 then print "Foo", if the number is divisible by 5 then print "Bar" and if the number is divisible by both 3 and 5, print "FooBar". Otherwise just print the number.

```
for example FooBar(15) should print as follows: 
1 
2 
Foo 
4 
Bar 
Foo 
7 
8 
Foo 
Bar 
11 
Foo 
13 
14 
FooBar
```

Its easy but the interview is checking for a better algorithm.

The first thing came to my mind is:

```
for i in xrange(1,101): print [i,'Fizz','Buzz','FizzBuzz'][(i%3==0)+2*(i%5==0)]
```

Please suggest if you ve any other ways of solving it.

Comment: What do you mean by "better?"  The assignment specifies three conditions.  With clever programming you might be able to get it down to two, but clever is not necessarily better.  If you want exhaustive coverage of this problem, you can Google "fizzbuzz;"  it's essentially the same algorithm.

Comment: More commonly known as [FizzBuzz](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/FizzBuzz).

Comment: oh thank you. let me check that.

Comment: Instead of `divmod(i,5)[1]` to find the modulus, it would be simpler to use Python's modulus operator `%` like so: `i % 5`

Comment: Just found out that this site has good information http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another solution, hope some body may like it.

```
values = ((3, "Foo"), (5, "Bar"))
for n in range(1, 101):
    res = ''.join(v for (k, v) in values if not n % k)
    print(res if res else n)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
def foobar(n):
    for x in range(n):
        print x%3/2 * 'Foo' + x%5/4 * 'Bar' or x+1
```

Comment: this is sweet, i like it.

Comment: For Python3 use `print(x%3//2 * 'Foo' + x%5//4 * 'Bar' or x+1)`

Answer (score 1):

If a number is 0 mod 3 and 0 mod 5, it is 0 mod 15.

```
def foobar(n):                                                                                                                                                                                               
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        ret = ""
        if i%3==0:
            ret += 'Foo'
        if i%5==0:
            ret += 'Bar'

        if(ret):
            print ret
        else:
            print i
foobar(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> D = {3:"Foo", 5:"Bar", 6:"Foo", 9:"Foo", 10:"Bar", 12:"Foo", 0:"FooBar"}
>>> for i in range(1, 16):
...     print D.get(i%15, i)
... 
1
2
Foo
4
Bar
Foo
7
8
Foo
Bar
11
Foo
13
14
FooBar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> foobar = "FooBar   Foo  Bar Foo   Foo Bar  Foo   ".split(" ")
>>> for i in range(1, 16):
...     print foobar[i%15] or i
... 
1
2
Foo
4
Bar
Foo
7
8
Foo
Bar
11
Foo
13
14
FooBar
```

Comment: Foo is printing at 2 ?

Comment: @yopy, do you need to reload? that was an error when i originally posted it